# How to write a procedure in TCL that will use either a global dictionary or another one

Tags: tcl, global

I have a procedure that use a global dictionary. it is a global one because I need the procedure to be able to read inside the dictionary and update it.

I need to be able to use either this global dictionary `dict_glob1` or another dictionary `dict_glob2` depending on a argument of the procedure.

I could provide as argument the correct dictionary but then I'm afraid I won't be able to update it. In fact I guess I need to be able to provide only the "name" of the global dictionary. but I don't know how to link the "name" of the dictionary with the real dictionary inside the procedure.

Comment: You need `upvar` - https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is to use `upvar` (plus whatever logic you need to decode the argument) to give the variable you want to access/update a consistent local name within your procedure. That keeps the complexity in the vicinity of setting up the `upvar` call; everything after that is simple (or at least just as complex as it needs to be).

Here's a contrived version (`d` is just a local variable name that's a bit mnemonic for "dictionary"):

```
proc doTheThing {{argument "foo"}} {
    if {$argument eq "foo"} {
        upvar "#0" dict_glob1 d
    } else {
        upvar 1 dict_glob2 d
    }

    dict set d abc 123
}
```

It's *more normal* for variable names to be always passed as arguments by the caller. They can name global variables if they want. In that case, you'd get:

```
proc doTheThing {{varName "::dict_glob1"}} {
    upvar 1 $varName d
    dict set d abc 123
}
```

In this case, we're naming a global variable as a default argument, but the caller can override it to be any other name (either namespaced or in their scope) that they prefer it to be.

Comment: It's _recommended_ but not required for you to always provide the level parameter to `upvar` to avoid some weird argument parses. When you use `upvar` you *almost always* mean `upvar 1`...

Comment: thanks, but juste to be sure. if I modify the local dictionnary "d" will it modify the global dictionnary "dict_glob1" from which "d" is issued ?

Comment: The two variables are "the same" in all useful respects. Internally, the local variable implementation becomes a pointer to the global variable implementation; it's very very fast once the link is made.

Answer (score 0):

Donal's answer is of course correct and comprehensive for stock Tcl. I'll just add a note here that if you (or future readers) are using the extended argument handling provided by [parse_args](https://github.com/RubyLane/parse_args) then there is an argument property `-alias` for this situation:

```
set dict_glob1 {name glob1}
set dict_glob2 {name glob2}

proc doTheThing args {
    parse_args $args {
        -use     {-alias}
        -fooval  {-required}
    }
    dict set use foo $fooval
}

doTheThing -fooval first -use dict_glob1
doTheThing -use dict_glob2 -fooval second

puts "dict_glob1: $dict_glob1"    ;# prints "name glob1 foo first"
puts "dict_glob2: $dict_glob2"    ;# prints "name glob2 foo second"
```

In the same way as the direct `upvar` example, the name passed to the `-alias` argument can be a fully namespace qualified name to directly refer to a global variable instead of that name in the caller's frame.

If the option `-use` is not supplied in this example, no link will be made:

```
dotheThing -fooval third    ;# Not an error, but doesn't affect any variables here
```

It can be made a required option with the argument property `-required`:

```
proc doTheThing args {
    parse_args $args {
        -use    {-alias -required}
        -fooval {-required}
    }
    dict set use foo $fooval
}
doTheThing -fooval forth    ;# Now it's an error: "option -use is required"
```